# Multiplying a value chosen by drop down and a constant with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My problem is that I need to use the value that the user selected and a constant that doesn't matter to multiply them and to show the result in a text-box with ajax

```
<select name="service" style="width: 230px; margin-left: 30px; height: 30px;margin-bottom:15px;">
    <?php 
      $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from service_tbl");
      while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<option value=\"service1\">" . $row['serviceName'] . "</option>";
      }
    ?>
</select>
```

This is the drop-down list that I am getting the value from

```
<input type="text" name="total" id = "output"  readonly="" style="margin-left: 62px;margin-bottom:15px;width: 230px; height: 30px;"><br>
```

This is the text box that needs to update when the drop-down list changes value.

Comment: Where is the ajax part?

Comment: Are you aware the we are here to **help solve** not do it for you?

Comment: Here is a good place to start. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example without PHP. The AJAX call returns the constant.

```js
var multiplier;

$.getJSON("jsonResponse.php").done(function(response) {
    multiplier = response.constant; // simulate AJAX JSON response: {"constant": 1000}
})
.fail(function() {
    multiplier = 1000; // jsonResponse.php doesn't exist so this will run
})

$('#service').on('change', function() {
  var num = $('#service').val();
  if(num) {
    $('#output').val(num * multiplier);
  } else {
    $('#output').val('');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="service">
  <option value="">-- select a service --</option> 
  <option value="124">Service 124</option> 
  <option value="875">Service 875</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="total" id="output" readonly>
```

Comment: Click the "Run code snippet" to see the code in action. If you explain why you need AJAX, I'll happily update my answer.

Comment: I downvoted because the OP wants the ajax to be written, not the javascript portion. Please see the comments on the question.

Comment: @Cemal Added en AJAX example